# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 when trying to check String

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to check users input from textFormField and check it with correct answer from list 'question_list' In this page user should input correct data to TextFormField. In for loop I'm trying to check user input from String list 'answer' and from list 'questionList'. for loop in setState() gives error

Comment: which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Line with setState()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access an `index` that is greater than the list itself.

The problem is happening because you're using the list `.length` property. But the index of a list is *zero-based* (starts with zero)

Try replacing the `<=` for `<`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < question[0]['correct_answer'].length; i++) {
  if (question[0]['correct_answer'][i] == answer[i]) {
```

Comment: It helps thank you! But I faced another problem. Don't you know how to correctly fill List 'answer'? I fill it with user input from textField.  List<String> answer = [];
And textField where I fill it
child: TextFormField(
         
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      answer.insert(questionIndex.compareTo(0), value);
                                      print(value);
                                    },

Comment: Regarding your next question, it will be better if you open another question and provide more information so I can help you. You can mention me with @ on the comment so I can see it